# Simple combinatoric question

Tags: combinatorics

This highschool level math. Nonetheless, I find it 
difficult to come up with a precise, and satisfying 
argument as to why the following line of reasoning is incorrect.

Say we have a group of 5 Dutch men, en 2 French men. We want to 
select a group of 5 people out of these 7 men, such that at least
3 of them are Dutch. The correct calculation is as follows:

${5\choose 3}{2\choose 2} + {5 \choose 4}{2\choose 1} + {5\choose 5} = 21$,

which is easy to understand. I know, the next calculation is incorrect. A highschool student came with the following argument:

It must be ${5\choose 3}{4 \choose 2}=60$ : 
We choose 3 dutchmen, so with ${5\choose 3}$ the 'at least 3 Dutchmen part is satisfied'. Now there's 4 people left we can freely choose 2 men from, so times ${4\choose 2}$.  I find the argument quite appealing, although its wrong. And i can see why it is wrong. But i'm looking for an easily understandable argument for a high school student without going into too many technical details.

Greetings,

from Holland.

Comment: There is multiple counting. If A,B,C,D,E are the Dutch and F,G are the French then e.g. A,B,C|E,F and A,B,E|C,F are looked at as two different possibilities. Enneh, de groeten uit Holland :).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that in the second calculation, one is *overcounting* some groups of people.

For example, one could first pick $\{D_1,D_2,D_3\}$ and then $\{D_4,F_1\}$, or first pick $\{D_1,D_2,D_4\}$ and then $\{D_3,F_1\}$. The second calculation would count these as different choices, but of course their unions form the same group of people.

Comment: Thank you, ofcourse...the most simple explanation.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that every selection with more than $3$ Dutchmen is counted several times. Let the Dutchmen be $A,B,C,D$, and $E$ and the Frenchmen $1$ and $2$, and consider the selection $A,B,C,D,1$. The second calculation counts it $4$ times:

- once with $A,B$, and $C$ as the $3$ Dutch initially selected and $D$ and $1$ as the extra $2$;
- once with $A,B$, and $D$ as the $3$ Dutch initially selected and $CD$ and $1$ as the extra $2$;
- once with $A,C$, and $D$ as the $3$ Dutch initially selected and $B$ and $1$ as the extra $2$; and
- once with $B,C$, and $D$ as the $3$ Dutch initially selected and $A$ and $1$ as the extra $2$.

In fact each group with just one Frenchman is counted $\binom43=4$ times, and the group with no Frenchman is counted $\binom53=10$ times.

Answer (score 1):

Well, first of all, there are only 21 ways to select 5 people from 7, so the incorrect argument has *way* overcounted someone. The other answers detail which groupings are being overcounted.

Observe, however, that since there are only two non-Dutchmen, *every* subset of 5 must contain at least three Dutchmen, so this constraint is irrelevant and the number of ways to make the selection is simply ${7\choose5}$. Fortunately, this gives the same result as the more complicated solution.